# Querying objects for an array of attributes in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am trying to fetch chats for an array of users.
Chats schemas are defined like this:

```
const ChatSchema = new Schema<IChatSchema>(
  {
    messages: [
      {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "MessageSchema",
      },
    ],
    participants: [
      {
        type:Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "UserSchema",
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);
```

I have two usersnames 'A' and 'B' and I want to query common chats of those two users. Any idea how to do it?

User schema

```
const UserSchema = new Schema<IUserSchema>(
  {
    username: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique:true,
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);
```

I tried this approach but did not work.

```
let chat = await Chats.find({
    participants: { $elemMatch: { username: usernames } },
  })
```

I also tried this

```
let chat = await Chats.find({
    "participants.username": { $all: usernames },
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

I can think of a few ways:

Option A: Use aggregation to lookup the participants, then match the usernames
Option B: Use find to retrieve the user records from Users, then query Chats for matching ObjectID values
Option C: modify the schema so the chats also contain the usernames, so you can query them directly